# SQL: How to extract certain digits from an integer in an efficient way?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using google big query, and I have a field TIME as integer as HHMMSS. I need to extract certain digits to create 3 columns: TIME_SECOND, TIME_MINUTE, TIME_HOUR.

Example of TIME column & required integer columns:

```
   TIME     TIME_HOUR    TIME_MINUTE  TIME_SECOND
----------  ---------    ---------   ----------
     2      |  00     |    00     |      02
    10      |  00     |    00     |      10
   111      |  00     |    01     |      11
  1858      |  00     |    18     |      58  
 12316      |  01     |    23     |      16 
234559      |  23     |    45     |      59
```

Ideally it needs to be as efficient as possible as this calculation will be done over a large table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  time,
  CAST(time / 10000 AS INT64) AS time_hour,
  MOD(CAST(FLOOR(time / 100) AS INT64), 100) AS time_minute,
  MOD(time, 100 ) AS time_second 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row     time        time_hour   time_minute time_second  
1       2           0           0           2    
2       10          0           0           10   
3       111         0           1           11   
4       1858        0           18          58   
5       12316       1           23          16   
6       234559      23          45          59
```

Above produces integers - meantime in your sample output it looks like you might expect strings: (`00`, `01`, etc.) - if so - use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  time, 
  y[OFFSET(1)] AS time_hour,
  y[OFFSET(2)] AS time_minute,
  y[OFFSET(3)] AS time_second
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([CAST(10000000 + time AS STRING)]) x,
UNNEST([STRUCT(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(x, r'\d\d') AS y)])
```

with output

```
Row     time        time_hour   time_minute time_second  
1       2           00          00          02   
2       10          00          00          10   
3       111         00          01          11   
4       1858        00          18          58   
5       12316       01          23          16   
6       234559      23          45          59
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use arithmetic:

```
select (time / 10000) as time_hour,
       (floor(time / 100) % 100) as time_minute,
       (time % 100 )as time_second
```

Comment: @Bex . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: % returns error in bigquery: Syntax error: Illegal input character "%"